# How to run my web2py application from facebook?

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I have created one web2py application, now i have to deploy this application to facebook so the user can login to facebook and can access this application from there, is there any way to achieve this?

Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start understanding how Facebook apps works, after that you will be able to develop web apps using any framework and "deploy" that to be used as a facebook app.

Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/